# How do I capture button events when phone display is turned off

Tags: android

When using Slacker Radio on my android phone I am able to skip to the next song when the display is off by long pressing the volume button.

What part of the API should I be looking at to implement such a feature for my app?

Answer (score 0):

I think you might find what your looking for from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4983605/send-button-volume-button-action-listeners). You just need to listen for that specific key event. You might want to look into a WakeLock to keep your program active when the display is turned off.